# Orbit slider not resizing on mobile devices

Tags: android, wordpress, zurb-foundation, orbit

I've built a site with Foundation into Wordpress

The problem is the orbit slider doesn't resize on mobile devices when you tilt from portrait to landscape. I've searched the Foundation forums for a solution as I thought it might be the slider itself, but it doesn't look that way.

My only thought is that I have added a extra .row somewhere possibly?

index.php

```
<?php if  (is_home() ){ 

        get_sidebar(slider);                    //Orbit image slider
        get_sidebar(welcome);
        get_sidebar(lowergrid);
        get_sidebar(round);
        get_sidebar(latest);
        get_sidebar(testimonials);
                                             ?> 

    <?php   } else {

                    ?>

    <?php } ?>

        </div> <!-- end inner wrap-->

    </div><!-- off canvas menu-->

</div> <!-- end row -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

sidebar-slider:

```
    <ul class="example-orbit small-12 columns" id="slider" data-orbit>
    <li>
      <img src="<?php bloginfo ('template_url');?>/foundation/images/header-01.jpg" alt="Beautiful Hwange" />
      <div class="orbit-caption" id="cap-one">
        <h1>Beautiful Hwange</h1>
        <h4>on your doorstep</h4>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="<?php bloginfo ('template_url');?>/foundation/images/header-02.jpg" alt="Kudu" />
      <div class="orbit-caption">
        <h1>A slice of paradise</h1>
        <h4>for you to enjoy</h4>          
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well i won't exactly get into fixing your problem, but Foundation officialy deprecated the orbit slider due to various reasons:

> Orbit has been deprecated, meaning that it is no longer supported.
>   There's no need to worry though as we decided to leave it in
>   Foundation if you choose to continue using it. We explain it here.

[Source](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/orbit.html)

As said in documentation, try slick slider, which is really great and very flexible configuration wide.